# JIRA-Merging two subtasks of the same story into one subtask

Tags: merge, jira, summary, scrum

I am currently working on a story that has further subtasks in it. The developers later discovered that they made two subtasks by mistake and they are both actually part of each other, so now they want me to merge the both subtasks as one. Has anybody any idea how to do that? Or if its possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge issues. I would create a link between them as duplicates and close one of them. You may add the author of the first subtask as watcher for the second one, if you want.

If this happens frequently you may use an app from the marketplace:

1. [Issue Merger PRO for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212656/issue-merger-pro-for-jira?tab=pricing&hosting=datacenter) for Jira DC & Cloud (paid)
2. [Issue Merger for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1226477/issue-merger-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview) for cloud only (free)